# not able to use smart GWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt2

trying to use smart GWT

Using smart gwt 2.5 dowloded from link below

[smartgwt 2.5](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/downloads/list)

Firefox 6.0

I made a small web application project(**without smart GWT**) which is working fine.

Now in the *same project i *added smartGwt 2.5*
and added `<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>`
in `myprojet.gwt.xml` file.

but now when i am running the project it gives me following error:

```
[ERROR] [myprojet] - Unable to load module entry point class 
com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint (see associated exception for details)

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.isc is undefined
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invo keJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke (ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative( ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeV oid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNati veVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
at com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint.init(SmartG wtEntryPoint.java)
at com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint.onModuleLoa d(SmartGwtEntryPoint.java:239)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ e Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native MethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(De legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(Module Space.java:396)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadM odule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.proc essConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run( BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

when i remove the `<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>`
from `myprojet.gwt.xml file` the project works fine

---

XML

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />


<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' />

<!-- Other module inherits -->

<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
<!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
<entry-point class='com.example.client.MyProjet' />

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
```

Comment: @HardikMishra  plz see the edited part

Comment: Its seems fine. Compile the project and clean brwoser cache and the try.

Comment: @HardikMishra yes its started working fine..
thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that. I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `gwt.xml` seems correct.

GWT Compile and cleaning brwoser cache should work.